# How to render variable to template in Django app

Tags: django, render

I'm developing Django app.

I want to render variable "q_word" to the template from this views.py

```
class DbList(ListView):
    model = TestEu
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        q_word = self.request.GET.get('query')

        if q_word:
            sql = 'select * from test_eu'
            sql += " where eng_discription ~ '.*" + q_word +".*'" 
            object_list = TestEu.objects.raw(sql)
            return object_list
```

Since "get_queryset" function apply "self" as first argument

```
def get_queryset(self):
```

I don't know how to apply below code to render.

```
return render(request, 'detail.html', {'q_word': q_word})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be passwed a `q_word` to the template. If you need access, you can however use:

```
{{ view.request.GET.query }}
```

or you can pass it to the context:

```
class DbList(ListView):
    model = TestEu
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(
            *args,
            q_word=self.request.GET.get('query'),
            **kwargs
        )

    def get_queryset(self):
        q_word = self.request.GET.get('query')

        if q_word:
            sql = 'select * from test_eu'
            sql += " where eng_discription ~ '.*" + q_word +".*'" 
            object_list = TestEu.objects.raw(sql)
            return object_list
```

Note that the query you make is vulnerable for [*SQL injection* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is one of the (many) reasons why using the Django ORM is better.